# Explanation of "in favor of"

Tags: questions

I have just read an article comparing two services, let's call them Maria and George.

The article concludes "I choose Maria in favor of George". I do not understand this structure?! "I choose Maria over George" would be clear to me, but here I am not sure if it means Maria or George was chosen?

Comment: Your focus on the misleading impression created by the way *favor* is used here makes for a good question. But I'm puzzled as to why you (or the article you were reading) would refer to two people as 'services'. Would you mind clarifying this?

Comment: It's easier for the discussion to employ the name of two people rather than using the actual technical names of the services that will not be understood by whoever doesn't have a knowledge in this particular technical field.

Comment: @maria: Since the usage is completely incorrect, it would have been helpful if you'd provided a link to the actual citation *in context*. Native speakers might be better able to establish *why* someone would write a thing like this (perhaps the author is a non-native speaker, or has clearly limited command of English and is writing outside their normal "register", for example).

Comment: Fumb - right; just click the "flag to close" button surely.

Comment: Hi Maria.  For the record you should have just left the original "highly technical" words.  People here are super-smart with language and could easily understand it.  Anyway your quote **is just a typo**.

Answer (score 3):

On purely semantic grounds, OP's example usage is simply *not valid English*. It should be...

> *"I **reject** Maria in favor of George"*

Note this definition from [dictionary.com...](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+favor+of)

> ***favor*** Idioms, sense 18
>    ***in favor of***
>    a. *on the side of; in support of: to be in favor of reduced taxation.*
>    b. *to the advantage of.*
>    c. *(of a check, draft, etc.) payable to: Make out your checks in favor of the corporation.*

Since OP's basic statement is *I choose Maria* it's difficult to see how doing this could be to George's advantage anyway (perhaps I'm choosing a human sacrifice! :). But regardless of such contrived contexts, the formula *reject/discard/ignore X **in favor of** Y* is a well-established construction in which ***Y*** benefits from the action (is favored), and ***X*** loses out (is denied or loses the benefit).

---

TL;DR: OP's example is syntactically possible, but because it clashes with existing idiomatic usage, I would reject it as *nonsensical* rather than simply *unusual*.

Answer (score 0):

This usage seems confusing, to say the least.

Having a look at [Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/favor), we find this:

> **7** behalf, interest
>    — in favor of
>   [...]
>   3 : in order to choose :  out of preference for *turned down the scholarship in favor of a pro career*

In that example, the *pro career* was favoured, it was chosen.

If I would write

> I turned down Maria in favour of George.

The sentence would clearly make sense. I favoured George, I selected him for the job.

The only way in which your sentence makes any logical sense, would be if I could on one hand select Maria to provide the service, and that would actually be beneficial to George - 
which would be the case if the service that Maria or George would have to provide is one they would rather not provide.

So if I am talking about a chore like, say, cleaning the lavatories, and my kids, Maria and George both hate doing that, I could say that I made my decision in favour of George, by selecting Maria to to it.

> I selected Maria to clean the toilets, in favour of George.

But that seems a bit far fetched, and without the rest of the context of the article, it is impossible to decide what the author actually meant.

Answer (score 0):

The quote you give is completely incorrect:

**it is s typographical error.**

OK?

It's hugely annoying on this site, when people use 1000s of inches of newsprint discussing / answering / commenting on questions where non-English speakers have asked about typos.

The only thing we all have to say in reply is: "oh that's a typo."  (Four words, right?)